# gmapping Map not updating correctly

Tags: navigation, laserscan, gmapping, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody.  I am having an issue with gmapping.  I have a simulated Rover that is publishing LaserScan messages and odometry data.  Basically I am seeing that when I drive my Rover next to an obstacle in a straight line, the occuppied cells created by gmapping (seen in rviz) moves with the Rover.  I have followed REP-103 and REP-105 and the "Seting up your robot using tf" as close as I can tell.  Sorry for the long post.

For tf frames I have:

```
geometry_msgs::Quaternion base_quat = tf::createQuaternionMsgFromYaw(0.0);
geometry_msgs::TransformStamped base_trans;
base_trans.header.stamp = current_time;
base_trans.header.frame_id = "odom";
base_trans.child_frame_id = "base_link";
base_trans.transform.translation.x = current_Northing_m;
base_trans.transform.translation.y = current_Easting_m;
base_trans.transform.translation.z = -0.2794;
base_trans.transform.rotation = base_quat;
base_broadcaster.sendTransform(base_trans);

geometry_msgs::Quaternion scan_quat = tf::createQuaternionMsgFromYaw(0.0);
geometry_msgs::TransformStamped scan_trans;
scan_trans.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
scan_trans.header.frame_id = "base_link";
scan_trans.child_frame_id = "laser";
scan_trans.transform.translation.x = 0.0;
scan_trans.transform.translation.y = 0.0;
scan_trans.transform.translation.z = 0.3556;
scan_trans.transform.rotation = scan_quat;
scan_broadcaster.sendTransform(scan_trans);
```

And my frame links:
[image: image description]

As you can see I am not doing anything with rotation yet.

And here are some pictures of my Simulated Rover in my GUI, along with the output of Rviz
When I start my program:
[image: image description]
[image: image description]

And now when the Rover is driven alongside the Obstacle:
[image: image description]
[image: image description]

And now when the Rover is driven well past the Obstacle:
[image: image description]
[image: image description]
As you can see, the Map is shifting with the Rover.

And here is some output of the gmapping package:

```
Odom Pose Theta: 0.000000 MPose Theta: 0.430916
GOT MAP
 Center x: -0.400000 y: -0.400000
 update frame 3624
 update ld=2.91054e-14 ad=0
 Laser Pose= 7.70492 -3 0
 m_count 108
 Average Scan Matching Score=499.238
 neff= 29.9807
 Registering Scans:Done
```

It is worth mentioning that in rviz, when I drive the Rover forwards, the Red axis on the tf frame is the one moving in the correct direction.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/218937/gmapping-map-not-updating-correctly./) by [davidgitz](https://answers.ros.org/users/13551/davidgitz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2015-10-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So the answer was to add: ,
link:http://answers.ros.org/question/83566/gmapping-no-transform-from-map-odom_combined/
which then creates a map that doesn't move with the Rover and is re-generated with new scan data.  However for my application this won't work apparently.  I am using Sonar sensors (not LIDAR) and the map it creates is just not very useful.  I knew this would be an issue from the start but hoped otherwise.  I will create my own occupancy grid generator.  Thanks for your help!

---

Originally posted by [davidgitz](https://answers.ros.org/users/13551/davidgitz/) with karma: 26 on 2015-10-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems like your simulated LaserScan does not properly fill beyond max range scan points. This makes gmapping update the map with the max range LIDAR end points, essentially leading the system to believe the robot is inside a round room. This of course leads to all sorts of problems, as the general shape of the LIDAR scan does not change, even though the robot is moving. The LIDAR scan for the round obstacle in your GUI also doesn't look quite as expected.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2015-10-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [davidgitz](https://answers.ros.org/users/13551/davidgitz/) on 2015-10-13**:
@Stefan - Thanks for this!  I found 2 bugs in my code, one that was not calculating when an obstacle was in view of the beam, and not setting the beam distance to -1 when no obstacle was present.  After fixing this though I am still seeing the same problems, does my tf structure/numbers make sense?

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2015-10-13**:
Do you still see the circles added to maps by gmapping? Note that a largely empty scenario is pretty challenging too because it doesn't have many features from which to localize.

**Comment by [davidgitz](https://answers.ros.org/users/13551/davidgitz/) on 2015-10-13**:
@Stefan - Yes I do.  I added 2 more obtacles.  When I drive the Rover forward the map moves along with the Rover.  Honestly I don't really care about the transform from odom -> map, I only want the occupancy grid.  Is there a way to just compute this with out the extra tf stuff?